# ROS buildfarm - Debian Buster Binary Job Failure (noetic)

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I recently made a release of [image_transport_plugins](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins) in ROS noetic, but the noetic debian binary builds have started failing afterwards.

Looking at the logs, the issue seems to be apt coming from an invocation of `apt-get install ... catkin` on the BuildFarm, but I can't quite figure out why `catkin` is getting installed rather than `ros-noetic-catkin`.

All logs have the following problem:

```
01:20:43 Invoking 'apt-get install -q -y -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes apt-src catkin debhelper image-transport-tools libcv-bridge-dev libdynamic-reconfigure-config-init-mutex-dev libgmock-dev libgtest-dev libimage-transport-dev libogg-dev librosbag-dev libstd-msgs-dev libtheora-dev pluginlib-dev python3-cv-bridge python3-dynamic-reconfigure python3-rosbag python3-std-msgs ros-message-generation ros-std-msgs'
01:20:43 Reading package lists...
01:20:44 Building dependency tree...
01:20:44 Reading state information...
01:20:44 Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 5
01:20:44 Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 5
...
```

Does anyone know, or have come across similar issues?

Buildfarm failures Logs:

[Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__theora_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__theora_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary/49/)
[Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__compressed_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__compressed_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary/48/display/redirect)
[Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__compressed_depth_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__compressed_depth_image_transport__debian_buster_arm64__binary/48/display/redirect)
[Nbin_db_dB64__theora_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_db_dB64__theora_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary/49/display/redirect)
[Nbin_db_dB64__compressed_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_db_dB64__compressed_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary/51/display/redirect)
[Nbin_db_dB64__compressed_depth_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_db_dB64__compressed_depth_image_transport__debian_buster_amd64__binary/50/display/redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [ros/rosdistro PR](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/35994) which included this release, the bloom version used was `0.10.7` which is quite old compared to the current `0.11.2` version from the time of the release PR.

I have not been able to determine what is causing this with older bloom versions on current distributions but using the current version of bloom to re-run `bloom-release ...`  resolves it.